# Background gradient shows a black horizontal line glitch in Firefox

Tags: css

Why do I get the horizontal line glitch in Firefox 88 (on Mac) when I use a background gradient?

```
.tristana {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #5577BA 0%, #2CA6BC 100%);
}
```

[image: Firefox background gradient horizontal line glitch]

### Demo

https://codepen.io/evgenyneu/full/eYvmYVK